# Zend require_once(library) unexpected error

Tags: zend-framework, require-once

I have setup a Zend project on cloudcontrol.com and after setting up everything, running it gives me the following error:

```
Warning: require_once(/srv/www/code/library): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/www/code/library/Zend/View.php on line 64

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '' (include_path='/srv/www/code/library:.:/usr/share/php') in /srv/www/code/library/Zend/View.php on line 64
```

Whereas `Zend/View.php on line 61` is inside of `Zend_View::__constructor()` as follows:

```
require_once 'Zend/View/Stream.php';
```

As it is evident from the error, the include path is fine. If I remove this line from here and put it before `Zend_View` class definition (say line 27), it works fine.

Any help would be much appreciated.

P.S. I'm not a noob in ZF1 development. Also, this exact same code is running fine on two servers. This problem only happens on cloudcontrol.

Comment: Does the file `/src/www/code/library/Zend/View/Stream.php` exist?

Comment: Of course it does. As I said, this line is in the constructor of Zend_View class. If I place it before the class definition within the same file, everything works prefectly

Answer (score 0):

you need to set include path for library like I have set this in my index.php file

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/library',
    dirname(__FILE__) . '/library',
    get_include_path(),
)));
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Look at the error brother. The path to library is in the include path because I put it there :)